# Mass of gaseous ammonia required to prepare ammonia solution of a given pH

Tags: aqueous-solution, ph, concentration

> How many grams of gaseous ammonia do you need to make $\pu{200 mL}$ aqueous ammonia solution with $\mathrm{pH} = 11.34?$

As the mole ratio is the same for $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{NH3},$

$$\ce{NH3 + H+ -> NH4+}$$

$$n(\ce{NH3(aq)}) = (\pu{10^{-11.34} mol L^-1})(\pu{0.200 L}) = \pu{9.14E-13 mol}$$

$$m(\ce{NH3(g)}) = (\pu{9.14E-13 mol})(\pu{17.031 g mol^-1}) = \pu{1.6E-11 g}$$

The answer seems way too small. What have I not taken into the account?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/139089

Comment: *As the mole ratio is the same for H+ and NH3,* - It is not. Not even close. Off by multiple orders.

Comment: @Poutnik Isn't the ratio for H+ and NH3, 1:1, seen the equation? NH3 + H+⟶ NH4+

Comment: That is ratio for the reaction, not for the occurence, There is more than $\pu{e10}$ times more NH3 than H+.

Comment: @Poutnik Thank you, I know at least one mistake now

Comment: Search for calculation of pH of solutions of weak bases. Internet is full of related content.

Comment: @Poutnik pOH + pH = 14, 
14 – 11,34 = 2,66, 
10^(-2,66) x 0,200 = 0,00218 x 0,200 = 0,000436 mol OH-,
Mole ratio reaction -> OH- : NH3 = 1 : 1, 
0,000436 x 17,031 = 0,0074 gram = 7,4 x 10^(-3) g gaseous ammonia. Would you say this is correct?

Comment: Amount ratio OH- : NH3 is not 1 : 1 either. You are closer, but still few orders off. You are guessing. // Kb = 10^(-4.75)=[NH4+][OH-]/[NH3]

Answer (score 0):

This problem is an equilibrium problem, and namely the following equilibrium : $$\ce{NH3 + H2O = NH4^+ + OH-}$$ The tables give the equilibrium constant : $$\ce{$K$_b = \frac{[NH4^+][OH-]}{[NH3]} = 1.8 10^{-5}}$$ Let's define $c$ as the total concentration of $\ce{NH3}$ brought into solution (included the part transformed into $\ce{NH4^+}$), of which the amount $\alpha$ (< $c$) has been reacted and transformed into $\ce{NH4+ and OH-}$. The problem is to find the value of $c$. Now $c$ - $\alpha$ is the residual concentration of $\ce{NH3}$ in solution.

As the final pH is $11.34$, $\pu{[OH^-]}$ = $\alpha$ = $\pu{\frac{10^{-14}}{[H^+]} = 10^{-14 + 11.34} = 10^{-2.66}}$. This $\ce{[OH-]}$ is also equal to $\ce{[NH4^+]}$ Introducing this value in $K_b$  yields : $$\ce{$K$_b = 1.8 10^{-5} = \frac{\alpha^2}{c - \alpha} = \frac{{10^{-5.32}}}{c - 10^{-2.66}}}$$ The value of the concentration $c$ is :  $$c - \pu{10^{-2.66} = \frac {10^{-5.32}}{1.8· 10^{-5}} = 0.05555} \mathrm{mol/L}   $$ As $\ce{10^{-2.66} = 0.002188}$ it gives : $$c = 0.0577 \mathrm{mol/L}$$ $$n\ce{(NH3) = 0.2 \mathrm{L} · 0.0577} \mathrm {mol/L} = 0.01154 \mathrm{mol}$$ This corresponds to a volume of gaseous $\ce{NH3}$ equal to $$\ce{V(NH3) = \frac{$nRT$}{$P$} = 0.01154\frac{$RT$}{$P$} = 0.282 L}$$

Comment: I just calculated it myself and saw your comment, I'm very glad it seems to be the same as you have deduced. It's convenient to be able to remove some of my doubts, much appreciated!